# jQuery on.blur allows user to continue during form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, onblur

My code pops up a modal if a textbox value exceeds the maximum available, but allow the user to click in another box after closing the modal.  And then pops up the validation modal again on the next click.  Basically shows the validation message but allows the user to click the save button anyway.  Why does the onBlur only kickoff every other click?  What do I need to do to stop the user from continuing until the error is resolved? If I set focus the program just loops.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     // bind the popovers to show the content
     $('.JOHN_formButtonPopover').popover({
         trigger: "hover",
         placement: "top"
     });

     // calculations to do when numbers are entered in the text boxes 
     $(document).on('blur', '.JOHN_textInput', function() {
         var $this = $(this);


         var totalAVAILEntered = 0;
         var hasError = false;

         // cycle through the textboxes to add up the numbers in them to subtract from the total available
         $('.JOHN_textInput').each(function() {
             var $textBox = $(this);

             // if the textbox isn't empty, try to parse the content as a number
             if ($textBox.val() != "") {
                 var currentValue = parseInt($textBox.val());

                 // if it is a valid number, add to the total to subtract from the overall available
                 if (currentValue >= 0) {
                     totalAVAILEntered += currentValue;
                 }
                 // else, there is an error. Show appropriate message in a modal
                 else {
                     $('#JOHN_informationDetails').text('Number is either invalid or negative!');
                     $('#modal_informationMessage').modal('show');
                     hasError = true;
                     return;
                 }
             }
         });

         // If all numbers were parsed correctly, do appropriate calculations
         if (!hasError) {
             var initialAVAILAvailable = parseInt($('#JOHN_totalAVAILAvailable').attr('data-initialAmountLeft'));

             var initCategoryDollars = parseInt($('#hiddenInitialValue').attr('data-InitialCategoryDollars'));

             // numbers add up to 0 - keep original available entered from page load
             if (totalAVAILEntered == 0) {
                 $('#JOHN_totalAVAILAvailable').text(initialAVAILAvailable);
                 $('#JOHN_informationDetails').text('At least one category must have an amount.');
                 $('#modal_informationMessage').modal('show');
             } else if (totalAVAILEntered <= initialAVAILAvailable) {

                 $('#JOHN_totalAVAILAvailable').text(initialAVAILAvailable - totalAVAILEntered + initCategoryDollars);
             }
             // else, the user entered a number too large. Inform them that they need to adjust the amount entered
             else {
                 var message = 'The amount entered is too high. You cannot enter this much';

                 CreateInformationMessage(message);

             }

         }

     });
 });
```

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            <h3>Total Available : $<span data-initialamountleft="353960" id="JOHN_totalAvailable">353960</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form>
        <input data-initialcategorydollars="4440" id="hiddenInitialValue" type="hidden"><br>
    </form>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-left">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-left">
                    <label class="JOHN_textLabel" for="categoryTypeDDnew_CategoryType_4_">21** ( Travel )</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            $
                        </div><input class="form-control JOHN_textInput text-right" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Decimal must be a number." data-val-required="The Decimal field is required." id="CategoryType_CategoryType_4" name="categoryDollarsNew[CategoryType_4]" placeholder="Enter a Number..." type="text" value="100.0000">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-left">
                    <label class="JOHN_textLabel" for="categoryTypeDDnew_CategoryType_2_">23** ( Contractual )</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            $
                        </div><input class="form-control JOHN_textInput text-right" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Decimal must be a number." data-val-required="The Decimal field is required." id="CategoryType_CategoryType_2" name="categoryDollarsNew[CategoryType_2]" placeholder="Enter a Number..." type="text" value="1260.0000">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-left">
                    <label class="JOHN_textLabel" for="categoryTypeDDnew_CategoryType_1_">25** ( Contractual )</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            $
                        </div><input class="form-control JOHN_textInput text-right" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Decimal must be a number." data-val-required="The Decimal field is required." id="CategoryType_CategoryType_1" name="categoryDollarsNew[CategoryType_1]" placeholder="Enter a Number..." type="text" value="3000.0000">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-left">
                    <label class="JOHN_textLabel" for="categoryTypeDDnew_CategoryType_3_">26** ( Supplies )</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            $
                        </div><input class="form-control JOHN_textInput text-right" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Decimal must be a number." data-val-required="The Decimal field is required." id="CategoryType_CategoryType_3" name="categoryDollarsNew[CategoryType_3]" placeholder="Enter a Number..." type="text" value="40.0000">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-left">
                    <label class="JOHN_textLabel" for="categoryTypeDDnew_CategoryType_5_">31** ( Equipment )</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 text-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            $
                        </div><input class="form-control JOHN_textInput text-right" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Decimal must be a number." data-val-required="The Decimal field is required." id="CategoryType_CategoryType_5" name="categoryDollarsNew[CategoryType_5]" placeholder="Enter a Number..." type="text" value="40.0000">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 text-left"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary JOHN_formButtonPopover" data-content="Save your plan, but do not submit it for review." data-toggle="popover" id="button_SavePlan" name="button_SavePlan" onclick="SavePlan();">Save</button> <button class="btn btn-default JOHN_formButtonPopover" data-content="Discard changes and return to listing screen." data-toggle="popover" id="button_Cancel" name="button_Cancel" onclick="Cancel();">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML that goes along with this? A JSFiddle would be especially helpful.

Comment: do you have more than one input with the class ".JOHN_textInput" in your example you have bound blur to just that selector.

Comment: Yes ...there are several key value pairs for .JOHN_textInput.  I'm going to include the HTML now....

Comment: JavaScript does not care anything about your framework.  Rather than posting your server-side "HTML"... please post the ***rendered*** HTML as recieved by the browser.